# Meta query relation 'OR' not working as expected

Tags: custom-field, wp-query

I have the following query, `$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );`, which is supposed to show any properties of H_property_type **bandb**, **hotel** *or* **dining**.

If I do a print_r of $args I get the following, which I would expect to work great:

```
Array(
[post_type] => property
[posts_per_page] => -1
[orderby] => H_featured
[order] => DESC
[meta_query] => Array
    (
        [relation] => OR
        [0] => Array
            (
                [key] => H_property_type
                [value] => bandb
                [compare] => on
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [key] => H_property_type
                [value] => hotel
                [compare] => on
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [key] => H_property_type
                [value] => dining
                [compare] => on
            )
    )
)
```

But for some reason this technique is only retrieving results for one of the checkboxes - i.e. they ALL have the H_property_type of hotel.

What am I doing wrong?

My arguments are set up using this bit of code:

```
if(isset($_GET['H_property_type'])){
    if(count($_GET['H_property_type']) > 1){
        $args['meta_query']['relation'] = 'OR';
    }
    foreach ($_GET['H_property_type'] as $type) {
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'H_property_type',
            'value' => $type,
            'compare' => 'on'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you see the `compare` value to 'on' ? Do you want any of the `H_property_type` value or all of the `H_property_type` to match the value ?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for this, most probably. Note: meta query support a compare method what is 'IN', which means any of the value. Like this -

```
if( isset($_GET['H_property_type']) ){
    // you don't need relation for this
    // if(count($_GET['H_property_type']) > 1){
    //    $args['meta_query']['relation'] = 'OR';
    // }
    // if $_GET['H_property_type'] is an array
    // foreach ($_GET['H_property_type'] as $type) {
    if( isset($_GET['H_property_type']) && is_array($_GET['H_property_type']) ){
        $args['meta_query'] = array(
            'key' => 'H_property_type',
            'value' => array_map( 'trim', $_GET['H_property_type'] ),
            'compare' => 'IN'
        );
    }
    // }
}
```

Commented codes are not necessary for the query. Thanks.